# Arquillian configurations

Tags: jboss-arquillian

Is there anyone out there who could tell me how to configure Arquillian on IntelliJ 14 Ultimate (on Mac OS x Yosemite) to test my Maven based project's JPA and Session beans please? I have tried the tutorials and nothing seems to work.

Thanks

Comment: I'm using WildFly 9.0 , Java EJB, JPA and JSF

Comment: could you post the error you are getting and the configuration you are using?

Comment: I have configured it as per the tutorial on arquillian.org to test CDI. But when I add the embeddeble glassfish or JBOSS 7.11 it does not work. For example JBOss simply hangs when its trying to start. Glassfish says socket closed (amogst other things) I dont hove the errors at the moment as I am at work (This is my MSc project) I'll post the errors when I go home. Thanks for your efforts to help me

Comment: Is your project publicly available?